# Node.js running a shell command from the same process

Tags: javascript, node.js, minecraft, raspbian

I'm trying to make a way to boot up a Minecraft server from nodejs, but I'm having trouble making a way to run commands from nodejs.

```
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process')
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/start', (req, res) => {
  fs.writeFile('minecraftstatus.txt', 'on', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
  const command = spawn('java',  ['-jar', '-Xms2048M','-Xmx2048M', '-Dfile.encoding=utf8', 'server.jar', 'nogui'])

  // the `data` event is fired every time data is
  // output from the command
  command.stdout.on('data', output => {
      // the output data is captured and printed in the callback
      fs.appendFile('console.txt', ("\n" + output.toString()), 'utf-8', err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
      console.log("Output: ", output.toString())
  })

  res.status(200).send("OK")
});

app.listen(80, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 80');
});
```

From what you see above, whenever a user sends a GET request, it sends a command and appends any output to a text file. I need to make a way in order to send commands to Minecraft. I need to send commands to the same shell that nodejs ran the command.

I've tried this:

```
app.get('/mcstop', (req, res) => {
    try {
      const command2 = spawn('/stop')

      // the `data` event is fired every time data is
      // output from the command
      command2.stdout.on('data', output => {
          // the output data is captured and printed in the callback
          console.log("Output: ", output.toString())
      })

      res.status(200).send("OK")
    }
    catch {
      console.log("Oh no...")
    }
});
```

Where it sends /stop to the shell, but it seems like it isn't being ran on the same shell as where the Minecraft server was created from.

How could I achieve this?